# PHP: Is there a command that merges arrays of the same key and sums content with the same keys

Tags: php, algorithm, array-merge

I have 2 arrays of arrays which I want to merge by keys for the first step and them sum on the second step - example:

```
Array
(
    [2017-03-01] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 2
            [bananas]   => 1
        )

    [2017-03-02] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 3
            [bananas]   => 6
        )

    [2017-03-03] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 0
            [bananas]   => 4
        )
}


Array
(
    [2017-03-01] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 3
            [bananas]   => 2
        )

    [2017-03-02] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 4
            [bananas]   => 7
        )

    [2017-03-03] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 1
            [bananas]   => 5
        )
}
```

Wanted result:

```
Array
(
    [2017-03-01] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 5
            [bananas]   => 3
        )

    [2017-03-02] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 7
            [bananas]   => 13
        )

    [2017-03-03] => Array
        (
            [apples]    => 1
            [bananas]   => 9
        )
}
```

Is there a command that does that (as a 1 single command) that will avoid looping through the arrays?

Comment: you may create your own function

Comment: There's no way to do this without looping through the arrays. What could exist (but doesn't) is a built in command that hides the looping from your code.

Answer (score 3):

No. (obligatory additional characters)

Comment: You're going to get downvoted now, that was a Yes/No question that you answered perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an insanely inefficient way of doing but without using any sort of `for` `foreach` or `while`

```
$result = array_map(function ($aentry, $key) use ($b) {
    $bentry = $b[$key] ?? [];
    $result = array_map(function ($value, $key) use ($bentry) {
        return [$key, $value + ($bentry[$key] ?? 0) ];
    },$aentry, array_keys($aentry));
    return [ $key, array_combine(array_column($result, 0), array_column($result, 1)) ];
}, $a,array_keys($a));

$result = array_combine(array_column($result, 0), array_column($result, 1));
```

Example:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c1dca3057c33dd17d0106666a497c7b08e57038

Comment: I know you already said as much but for what it's worth this takes roughly 3x longer than a foreach loop.   It's also ugly.  But I'm upvoting you anyway for creativity.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `for`,`foreach` or `while` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 question was asking whether there's a way to avoid looping and this code hides looping in built-in functions.

Comment: Fair enough. But it does looping anyway under the hood. Anyways, the OP does not seem to have much knowledge about it, so he/she framed such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without for/foreach/... , assuming that all keys are the same, you can do:

```
$array1 = [
    '2017-03-01' => [
        'apples'    => 2,
        'bananas'   => 1,
    ],
    '2017-03-02' => [
        'apples'    => 3,
        'bananas'   => 6,
    ],
    '2017-03-03' => [
        'apples'    => 0,
        'bananas'   => 4,
    ],
];

$array2 = [
    '2017-03-01' => [
        'apples'    => 3,
        'bananas'   => 2,
    ],
    '2017-03-02' => [
        'apples'    => 4,
        'bananas'   => 7,
    ],
    '2017-03-03' => [
        'apples'    => 1,
        'bananas'   => 5,
    ],
];

array_walk($array1, function(&$subarray1, $key) use($array2) {
    array_walk($subarray1, function(&$element, $subkey) use($array2, $key) {
        $element += $array2[$key][$subkey];
    });
});
```

Not good performance, just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

## This may help you

`

```
$a = array('2017-03-01' => array('apples'=> 2, 'bananas'=>1),
    '2017-03-02' => array('apples'=> 3, 'bananas'=>6),
    '2017-03-03' => array('apples'=> 0, 'bananas'=>4));
```

```
$b=array('2017-03-01' => array('apples'=> 3, 'bananas'=>2),
'2017-03-02' => array('apples'=> 4, 'bananas'=>7),
'2017-03-03' => array('apples'=> 1, 'bananas'=>5));

$sumArray = array();
foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$key]['apples']=($a[$key]['apples']+$b[$key]['apples']);
    $sumArray[$key]['bananas']=($a[$key]['bananas']+$b[$key]['bananas']);   
}
```

print_r($sumArray);
`

Comment: I think you forgot to close your parenthesis when declaring $a and $b

Comment: @Bentaye, **Thank u**

Comment: Solution should be able to merge arrays which don't have `apples` and `bananas` in them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, here is my code:

```
function merge_fruit_data($new_data, $old_data){ 

    // If it's the first time running - return new data as an array 
    if (empty($old_data)){
        return $new_data;
    }
    else {

        foreach ( $new_data as $key => $insert_new_data ) {

            if ( !$old_data[$key] ) {
                $old_data[$key] = $insert_new_data;
            }
            else{
                $old_data[$key]['apples']  += $insert_new_data['apples'];
                $old_data[$key]['bananas'] += $insert_new_data['bananas'];
            }
        }

    }

    return $old_data;
}
```

Efficiency comments are welcome.

Comment: Solution should be able to merge arrays which don't have `apples` and `bananas` in them as well